# CURL не работает в ajax-запросе

Tags: ajax, curl

Всем привет. Помогите решить задачку с Курл-ом, который почему-то в связке с ajax-ом отказывается работать. 
И так, есть файл (https://name.ru/output/out.php), где прописан простой CURL-запрос:

```html
<?php 
function getSavePage($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 512);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);    
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2600.0 Iron Safari/537.36');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}   

   $url = 'http://site-name.ru/images/photo.png'; 
   echo json_encode(getSavePage($url)); 
   die();      
 ?>
```

Далее есть файл обработчик события в ajax.js, где с помощью ajax передаю данные в файл out.php для получения данных от CURL.

```html
<script>
$('.btn-parse-content').click(function() { 
      
        var data = {};  
        data.id_cnt = '123';
 
  $.ajax({
       url: 'https://name.ru/output/out.php',       
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){
      
        },
        success: function(result){
      
         console.log(result); 
   
        },
        error: function(){
 
     return(false);     
                }
      });

  return false;
});
</script>
```

Короче, в ответе приходит null, как я не крутил, курл не работает. Обращаюсь к файлу на прямую https://name.ru/output/out.php - курл работает в ответе получаю нужные данные. Может кто знает в чем может быть дело, почему через простой аякс-запрос не работает, а на прямую - без проблем?

Answer (score 0):

Все разобрался. Проблема была в url для сохранения файла. Путь надо было указать относительно директории.

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko, это же ответ.